# jquery plugin conflict - display none becomes the default option on hard refresh but not by default

Tags: jquery-plugins, conflict

I am using two jquery plugins:

hero carousel and content hover.

Initially when I load the page the content hover works correctly, however when I carry out a hard refresh on the page it seems to default to display:none.

I have tried disabling the hero carousel plugin and this resolves the problem but I have no idea where the conflict may be between the two plugins.

I would paste all the code but that would mean pasting two huge chunks of jquery, the site in its current state can be found [here](http://tonysandwich.co.uk/mk1golf) the content hover plugin is currently on the bottom left image under the slider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take these two scripts:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hero-carousel').heroCarousel({
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
         css3pieFix: true
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$('#d1').contenthover({
    overlay_background:'#F25342',
    overlay_opacity:0.8
});
</script>
```

And put them together like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hero-carousel').heroCarousel({
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        css3pieFix: true
    });

    $('#d1').contenthover({
        overlay_background:'#F25342',
        overlay_opacity:0.8
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I do not see any script binding your second carousel function. I also do not see the easing library which is available here: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ You'll need that because you are using easing in your carousel function above.